# Value of integer bit field is alternately equal to 0 or 1 when bit field width is less than the needed

Tags: c, testing, struct, enums, bit-fields

I am testing a code in C where i intentionally define an integer bit field(*variable not_enough*) inside a struct to width 1 but assign values which require 2 or 3 bits. **It is important to note that i get the values from an enum**. After this, i print the values. I would expect to either get default value of integer equal to 0. But what i get is value alternately equal to 0 or 1.

Can you please explain why?

Here is the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum {
    FIRST = 9,
    SECOND = 8,
    THIRD = 7,
    FOURTH = 6,
    FIFTH = 5,
    SIXTH = 4,
    SEVENTH = 3,
    EIGHTH = 2
} directionValues;

struct {
    unsigned int enough : 3;
    unsigned int not_enough: 1; //intentionally limited to 1 bit
} test_bit;

int main(void) {

    test_bit.enough = EIGHTH;
    printf("Enough bits for variable. Value is %d\n",test_bit.enough);

    test_bit.not_enough = THIRD;
    printf("Not enough bits for variable. Value is %d\n",test_bit.not_enough);
    test_bit.not_enough = FOURTH;
    printf("Not enough bits for variable. Value is %d\n",test_bit.not_enough);
    test_bit.not_enough = FIFTH;
    printf("Not enough bits for variable. Value is %d\n",test_bit.not_enough);
    test_bit.not_enough = SIXTH;
    printf("Not enough bits for variable. Value is %d\n",test_bit.not_enough);
    test_bit.not_enough = SEVENTH;
    printf("Not enough bits for variable. Value is %d\n",test_bit.not_enough);
    test_bit.not_enough = EIGHTH;
    printf("Not enough bits for variable. Value is %d\n",test_bit.not_enough);

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

> Enough bits for variable. Value is 2
>
> Not enough bits for variable. Value is 1
>
> Not enough bits for variable. Value is 0
>
> Not enough bits for variable. Value is 1
>
> Not enough bits for variable. Value is 0
>
> Not enough bits for variable. Value is 1
>
> Not enough bits for variable. Value is 0

Comment: "It is important to note that i get the values from an enum" - no, it is not! And you use _enum-constants_, not the 'enum' type. As you consider `1` not being UB: whchich behaviour would you accept as UB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because only last bit is set to your variable because it has 1 bit allowed only.

You are actually doing this:

```
test_bit.not_enough = 7; //(0111) Bit 0 is 1
printf("Not enough bits for variable. Value is %d\n",test_bit.not_enough);
test_bit.not_enough = 6; //(0110) Bit 0 is 0
printf("Not enough bits for variable. Value is %d\n",test_bit.not_enough);
test_bit.not_enough = 5; //(0101) Bit 0 is 1
printf("Not enough bits for variable. Value is %d\n",test_bit.not_enough);
test_bit.not_enough = 4; //(0100) Bit 0 is 0
printf("Not enough bits for variable. Value is %d\n",test_bit.not_enough);
test_bit.not_enough = 3; //(0011) Bit 0 is 1
printf("Not enough bits for variable. Value is %d\n",test_bit.not_enough);
test_bit.not_enough = 2; //(0010) Bit 0 is 0
printf("Not enough bits for variable. Value is %d\n",test_bit.not_enough);
```

Since you have only 1 bit available memory, only first bit (LSB) is set to your variable.

Answer (score 1):

What's undefined behaviour anyway - you cannot know something is *not* undefined behaviour in C by just observing it it could be that alternating 1's and 0's is an example of undefined behaviour.

However, the C standard says that in this case there is no undefined behaviour. The value of these enums is converted to an unsigned int of 1 bit wide by taking the value modulo 2. Quoting [C11 6.3.1.3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3):

> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, **if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.**
>
> 2 Otherwise, **if the new type is unsigned**, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting **one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.** 60)
>
> 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

With footnote 60 stating:

> The rules describe arithmetic on the mathematical value, not the value of a given type of expression.

Any integer value can be converted to an unsigned int bit-field of 1 bit without undefined behaviour - not even implementation-defined. The value stored will be

- 0, if the original value is even
- 1, if the original value is odd

(even numbers are `0 + 2*k` and odd numbers `1 + 2*k` - here the `2k` matches the *repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type" - i.e. *2* is added or subtracted *|k|* times.

Alternatively, if the original number is unsigned, the value stored is the least significant bit; if the original number is signed and the implementation uses 2's complement representation, the value stored is again the least significant bit.

Comment: @Anhtti It seems that tilz0R's answer is correct. If for example i change width to 2 bits and all the values equal to 7, i always get value = 3(7 = 111 in binary, using 2 bits, then 3 = 11 in binary). Can you explain this using your statements above? Why is repeatedly adding or subtracting not working in this case?